# Kivy: updating marker center location based on underlaying Scatter

Tags: python, kivy

I'm having a problem updating the location of the previously pinned location (implemented as custom round button Marker inheriting from BellyButton) so that the center of the button is always in the same place, no matter what scale or position has the underlying Scatter. I'm doing it this way so that the button size doesn't get scaled with the scatter.

The code below is simplified version of the one I'm using with database - that's why it has so many methods etc. I need `belly_pos` and `belly_text` to write those to database.

What I've figured out so far is that **`Marker.pos` stays in the correct place** for maker instances when scaling and dragging Scatter, but I don't know why - because I'm updating `belly_pos` which is `Marker.center` effectively, not `Marker.pos`. I've added some lines to canvas to better illustrate it.

Consider the following code (You need to **place some picture as 'map.jpg'** to the same folder):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.logger import Logger as logging
import kivy.metrics as kvmetrics

from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

from kivy.uix.behaviors.button import ButtonBehavior

from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label

from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty

kivy_lang = '''
<ProjectMap>:
    BoxLayout:
        id: main_box
    BellyButton:
        id: add_new
        belly_pos: (root.size[0]-self.size[0]/2,root.y+self.size[1]/2)
        belly_text: "+"
        on_press: root.add_marker()

<MapScatter>:
    scatter_pos: imgscatter.pos
    scatter_scale: imgscatter.scale
    Scatter:
        id: imgscatter
        size_hint: None, None
        size: img.size
        auto_bring_to_front: False
        do_rotation: False
        Image:
            id: img
            source: root.map_path
#            pos: imgscatter.pos
            size: self.texture_size
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
                BorderImage:
                    border: (root.image_border,root.image_border,root.image_border,root.image_border)
                    size: (self.width+2*root.image_border,self.height+2*root.image_border)
                    pos: (-1*root.image_border,-1*root.image_border)


<BellyButton>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: (belly_label.texture_size[1]*1.2, belly_label.texture_size[1]*1.2)
    center: self.belly_pos
    canvas.after:
        Color:
            rgba: 0,1,0,1
        Line:
            points: self.x, self.y, self.x+10, self.y+10

    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: self.belly_color
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
        Line:
            points: self.x, self.y, self.center[0], self.center[1]
    Label:
        id: belly_label
        size: self.texture_size
        font_size: sp(app.gui_multiplier)
        pos: [root.center_x-self.size[0]/2,root.center_y-self.size[1]/2]
        text: root.belly_text

<Marker>:

'''


class BellyButton(ButtonBehavior, Widget):
    belly_pos = ListProperty([0,0])
    belly_text = StringProperty('#')
    belly_color = ListProperty([1,0,0,1])

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BellyButton, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)

class Marker(BellyButton):
    location = [0,0]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Marker, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        #self.center = self.location

    def update_pos(self, offset, scale):
        self.belly_pos = [offset[0] +self.size[0]/2 +(self.location[0]) * scale, offset[1]+ self.size[1]/2+(self.location[1]) * scale]
        logging.info('''info: updated belly_pos context::
        current scatter pos: {}
        current scatter scale: {}
        saved marker location: {}
        calculated belly_pos: {}'''.format(offset,scale,self.location, self.belly_pos))
        return self.belly_pos

    def save_pos(self,offset,scale):
        self.location = [(self.location[0] - offset[0])/scale, (self.location[1] - offset[1])/scale]
        return self.location

class ProjectMap(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        FloatLayout.__init__(self,**kwargs)
        self.markers = []
        self.load_map()

    def load_map(self,**kwargs):
        self.ids.main_box.clear_widgets()
        self.ids.add_new.disabled = False

        self.current_map = MapScatter('map.jpg')
        self.current_map.bind(scatter_pos=self.transfer_pos)
        self.current_map.bind(scatter_scale=self.transfer_pos)

        for marker in self.markers:
            self.current_map.add_widget(marker)
        self.ids.main_box.add_widget(self.current_map)

        img_bigger_dim = self.current_map.ids.img.texture_size.index(max(self.current_map.ids.img.texture_size))
        self.current_map.ids.imgscatter.scale = 0.9 * Window.size[img_bigger_dim] / self.current_map.ids.imgscatter.size[0]
        self.current_map.ids.imgscatter.scale_min = 0.5 * self.current_map.ids.imgscatter.scale
        self.current_map.ids.imgscatter.center = (Window.size[0]/2,Window.size[1]/2)

    def transfer_pos(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for no in range(0,len(self.current_map.children)-1):
            self.current_map.children[no].update_pos(self.current_map.scatter_pos,self.current_map.scatter_scale)

    def add_marker(self,*args,**kwargs):
        # self.new_marker.destroy()
        self.new_marker = Marker()
        self.place_marker_hint()

    def place_marker_hint(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.marker_hint = BellyButton()
        self.marker_hint.belly_color[3] = 0.5
        self.marker_hint.belly_pos = self.center
        self.marker_hint.bind(on_press=self.save_marker)
        self.add_widget(self.marker_hint)
        self.ids.add_new.disabled = True

    def calc_new_marker_pos(self):
        self.new_marker.location = self.center
        self.new_marker.save_pos(self.current_map.scatter_pos,self.current_map.scatter_scale)
        logging.info('''info: marker saved location context::
        current window center: {}
        current window scatterMap scatter_pos: {}
        current window scatterMap scatter_scale: {}
        current scatterMap scatter size: {}
        current scatterMap img size: {}
        marker size: {}
        saved marker location: {}
        calculated new Marker belly_pos(its center): {}
        '''. format(self.center, self.current_map.scatter_pos, self.current_map.scatter_scale, self.current_map.ids.imgscatter.size, self.current_map.ids.img.size, self.new_marker.size, self.new_marker.location, self.new_marker.belly_pos ))

    def save_marker(self, *args):
        self.calc_new_marker_pos()
        self.new_marker.belly_text = str(len(self.current_map.children)-1)
        self.markers.append(self.new_marker)

        self.current_map.clear_widgets()
        self.remove_widget(self.marker_hint)
        self.load_map()

class MapScatter(FloatLayout):
    map_path = StringProperty('')
    scatter_pos = ListProperty([0,0])
    scatter_scale = NumericProperty(1.0)
    image_border = NumericProperty(1.0)

    def __init__(self, map_path,*args,**kwargs):
        FloatLayout.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
        self.map_path = map_path
        self.image_border = kvmetrics.sp(app.gui_multiplier)*0.1

class MyApp(App):
    gui_multiplier = NumericProperty(30)

    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(kivy_lang)
        return ProjectMap()

    def on_pause(self):
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MyApp()
    app.run()
```